# Replace first line of a text file in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file where I want to change only the first line of the file.  The file could be millions of rows long, so I'd rather not have to loop over everything, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do this.

I'd also like to apply some rules to the first line so that I replace instances of certain words with other words.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `RandomAccessFile` will do the trick, unless the length of the resulting line is different from the length of the original line.

If it turns out you are forced to perform a copy (where the first line is replaced and the rest of the data shall be copied as-is), I suggest using a `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`. First use `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` to read the first line. Modify it and write it to the `BufferedWriter`. Then use a `char[]` array to perform a brute-force copy of the remainder of the file. This will be more efficient than doing the copy line by line. Let me know if you need details..

Another option is to perform the reading and writing inside the same file. It'll be a bit more complex though. :) Let me know if you need details on this as well..

Comment: Can you pls provide some info if the length of the string to be replaced is different. Is it possible without copying to a new file

Comment: If the length is different you will at the very least have to re-write all bytes, either in the same file or in a different file.

Comment: Anyone have a code example of how to do this with RandomAccessFile?

Answer (score 4):

If the new line has a different amount of characters (bytes) than the original first line, you will have to re-write the whole file to get rid of the gap or avoid overwriting part of the second line.

Of course, various tools like `String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)` ([javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))) or the `RandomAccessFile` ([javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)) can help you with this task.

Answer (score 3):

You want a [RandomAccesssFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).  Using the file you can read and write wherever you want in the file.

It is much like an InputStream and OutputStream, but it allows reading and writing wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

apply a regex only once.
String.replaceFirst("regex", "replacementstring") : http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Open the file as RandomAccessFile. Read the 1st line into a string and then apply the change and then write the string back.

Comment: only if the length of line 1 doesn't change

Comment: "The file could be millions of rows long" -- good luck with regexps! LOL

Answer (score 0):

```
public void main() throws IOException {
    String newString = "The New String";
    File myFile = new File("PathToFile");
    // An array to store each line in the file
    ArrayList<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);
    while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        // Reads the file content into an array
        fileContent.add(myReader.nextLine());
    }
    myReader.close();
    // Removes Original Line
    fileContent.remove(0);
    // Enters New Line
    fileContent.add(0, newString);
    // Writes the new content to file
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("PathToFile");
    for (String eachLine : fileContent) {
        myWriter.write(eachLine + "\n");
    }
    myWriter.close();
}
```