# How can I replace the first line of a large file in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io, replace, line

I would like to blank out the first line of a text file in Java.  This file is several gigabytes and I do not want to do a copy.  Using the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202148/replace-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-java), I am attempting to do so using RandomAccessFile, however it is writing too much.

Here is my code:

```
RandomAccessFile raInputFile = new RandomAccessFile(inputFile, "rw");
origHeaderRow = raInputFile.readLine();
raInputFile.seek(0);
raInputFile.writeChars(Strings.repeat(" ",origHeaderRow.length()));
raInputFile.close();
```

And if you want some sample input and output, here is what happens:

Before:

```
first_name,last_name,age
Doug,Funny,10
Skeeter,Valentine,9
Patti,Mayonnaise,11
Doug,AlsoFunny,10
```

After:

```
                        alentine,9
Patti,Mayonnaise,11
Doug,AlsoFunny,10
```

In this example, in most editors the file correctly begins with 24 blank spaces, but 48 characters (including newlines) have been replaced.  After pasting into here I see strange question mark things.  The double size replacement makes me thing something involving encoding is getting messed up but I tried writeUTF with the same results.

Comment: Just so you know, it's impossible to edit a file "in place" with modern filesystems.  A new copy is always made.

Comment: What encoding is the file in? 1521? UTF8? UCS2?

Comment: @Dough, looks like Jon Skeet is there too as "Skeeter" :)

Comment: @toto2: It's not impossible in this case. Overwriting individual bytes is very simple. Deleting or inserting a byte is the thing that requires copying.

Comment: @Roland I can't find a reference, but I read that even if you overwrite bytes, a copy is made anyway on most modern filesystems.  I was very surprised, so I remembered.  I can't remember where it was... maybe it was not reliable.

Comment: @Roland I remember I read about this in the context of trying to wipe a hard drive: overwriting the content of files leaves the original files on the disk anyway (with no reference to the file placement, but a hacker could possibly reconstruct some files).

Comment: @Roland However maybe if you just overwrite bytes in one block, maybe only one new block is created.  I would be easy to test how long it takes to add one byte to file versus changing one byte... but I don't want to do it.

Comment: @toto2: Yes, safely deleting data is difficult if you want to do it right, but I don't think that's the point here. I think the original poster just wants to remove the header from the CSV file so that other programs will (hopefully) ignore the first empty line.

Comment: @Roland I think he does not want to waste time copying the file.  I'm not sure if one method is faster than another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char` in Java is 2 bytes.

use `writeBytes` instead.

```
raInputFile.writeBytes(Strings.repeat(" ",origHeaderRow.length()));
```

From [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29) looks exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As you are writing chars (which in Java are 16-bit) each character uses two bytes.
I suggest you try writing the number of bytes you wants otherwise your spaces will turn into `nul` and `space` bytes.