# How to remove first line of a text file in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace first line of a text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202148/replace-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-java)
>   [Java - Find a line in a file and remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove)

I am trying to find a way to remove the first line of text in a text file using java. Would like to use a scanner to do it...is there a good way to do it without the need of a tmp file?

Thanks.

Comment: For many uses, you should always use a temp file on the same partition, then use rename/move operation of the OS to atomically replace old file with the new, so the file is never only partially written.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
fileScanner.nextLine();
```

This will return the first line of text from the file and discard it because you don't store it anywhere.

To overwrite your existing file:

```
FileWriter fileStream = new FileWriter("my/path/for/file.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileStream);
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String next = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if(next.equals("\n")) 
       out.newLine();
    else 
       out.write(next);
    out.newLine();   
}
out.close();
```

Note that you will have to be catching and handling some `IOException`s this way.  Also, the `if()... else()...` statement is necessary in the `while()` loop to keep any line breaks present in your text file.

Comment: +1 Skipping the first line is the fastest and simple way to do this.

Comment: that's not the whole story. Your file still has the line.

Comment: Okay, I can add how to overwrite the other file.

Answer (score 18):

If your file is huge, you can use the following method that is performing the remove, in place, without using a temp file or loading all the content into memory.

```
public static void removeFirstLine(String fileName) throws IOException {  
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");          
     //Initial write position                                             
    long writePosition = raf.getFilePointer();                            
    raf.readLine();                                                       
    // Shift the next lines upwards.                                      
    long readPosition = raf.getFilePointer();                             

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];                                         
    int n;                                                                
    while (-1 != (n = raf.read(buff))) {                                  
        raf.seek(writePosition);                                          
        raf.write(buff, 0, n);                                            
        readPosition += n;                                                
        writePosition += n;                                               
        raf.seek(readPosition);                                           
    }                                                                     
    raf.setLength(writePosition);                                         
    raf.close();                                                          
}
```

Note that if your program is terminated while in the middle of the above loop you can end up with duplicated lines or corrupted file.

Comment: Ran a test with a file 3kb and 4mb. The 4mb file took 20 times more time than the 3kb file.

Answer (score 1):

Without temp file you must keep everything in main memory. The rest is straight forward: loop over the lines (ignoring the first) and store them in a collection. Then write the lines back to disk:

```
File path = new File("/path/to/file.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
ArrayList<String> coll = new ArrayList<String>();
scanner.nextLine();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    coll.add(line);
}

scanner.close();

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
for (String line : coll) {
    writer.write(line);
}

writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If file is not too big, you can read is into a byte array, find first new line symbol and write the rest of array into the file starting from position zero. Or you may use memory mapped file to do so.