# How to use Constructor Scanner in java programming to grasp number of lines in text file

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files, java.util.scanner, filewriter

I was trying to remove the first line in text file using java code referencing from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178397/how-to-remove-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-java) but still the scanner does not contain any text, so it write nothing in the text file, please help, what is then problem...? 
here is a peace of code,

```
    File path=new File("C:/Users/kassim Ismail/workspace/Coding/textdoc.txt");
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(path);
    FileWriter newread=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\kassim Ismail\\workspace\\Coding\\textdoc.txt");
    BufferedWriter newreader=new BufferedWriter(newread);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    String nextline=scan.nextLine();

    if(nextline.equals("\n")){
        newreader.newLine();
    }else{
    newreader.write(nextline);  
    }
    }
    scan.close();
    newreader.close();
    newread.close();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to delete the first line of text file.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding your question However if you would like I can give you sample code to delete the first line of a text file

Comment: it me be bet if you may give other code

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I was dizy so I wrote poor explanations, but I intended to say "it will be better if you send me other codes to remove the first line of text in a text file".

Comment: Did you tried to execute nextLine() once before the loop (if hasLine is true of course) to skip the first line ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I don't see any mistake in your code (reader/writer should work). One thing I am unsure about is wether the blank space in your Filepath is problematic or not (Some programs can't work with blank spaces in file paths I am not sure about Java though).

Maybe you could add some System.out.println("") statements for debugging purposes. For Example (testing if the input file exists):

```
System.out.println("Inputfile exists: "+path.exists())
```

printing the read line:

```
System.out.println("Read line: "+nextline)
```

Comment: I had already used {system.out.println(nextline) } but it prints nothing, which mean it is empty  But before I didn't  declare the file I used to declare the path directly into the scanner constructor at that time when {println(nextline)} it was printing the text file path. that it is.

Comment: So nextline beeing empty is an error? If so the problem is most likely File path = new File("..."); and the result of path.exists() would be interesting. If that returns 'false' there is most likely a problem with the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean removeTopLine(File file){
    try{
        boolean status = false;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        String content = "";
        int counter = 0;
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            if (counter > 0){
                content += s.nextLine();
            }
            counter++;
        } 
        writer.write(content);
        writer.close();
        status = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

This is a functional code snippet that would delete the first line of a file however there could be debate on efficiency.