# Delete specific line from text file

Tags: java

I want to have a method that will take the file path and then delete a specific line from a text file and this is the code I came up with.

**Method.java**

```
public class Method {
static void deletefileline(String file, Integer line) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> filecontent = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        File myObj = new File(file);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            filecontent.add(data);
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File f = new File(file);
    f.delete();
    filecontent.remove(line);
    try {
        File newfile = new File(file);
        newfile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An Error Occured");
    }
    for (Integer i = 0; i < filecontent.size(); i++) {
        String textToAppend = "\r\n" + filecontent.get(i);
        Path path = Paths.get(file);
        Files.write(path, textToAppend.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    deletefileline("src/test.txt", 1);
 }
}
```

This is the text file

test.txt

```
hi
hello
hii
helloo
```

This is the text file after i ran Methods.java

Output:

```
hi
hello
hii
helloo
```

It won't show it but at the first "hi" before that there is a space so it only added a space at line 1.

So the problem is that when it is running it only adds an extra line at line 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove first line of a text file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178397/how-to-remove-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-java)

Comment: According to `deletefileline("src/test.txt", 1)` the second line is tried to remove. The first one is index `0`.

Comment: Your program misses 3 imports and still doesn't run `import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;` and stills gives compile time error `javac Method.java
Method.java:36: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    deletefileline("src/test.txt", 1);
                  ^
1 error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is not the line removed?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

> - `E remove(int index)` Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
> - `boolean remove(Object o)` Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.

Since `Integer line` is `Object` and not a primitive data type `int`, this call

```
filecontent.remove(line);
```

tries to remove the line with a **content** equal to `new Integer(1)`.

Change the method argument to `int line` or add type cast to the call `filecontent.remove((int) line)`.

#### Why is an empty line added?

The extra space is added by this statement:

```
String textToAppend = "\r\n" + filecontent.get(i);
```

Change it like this:

```
String textToAppend = filecontent.get(i) + "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small snippet to perform same function as mentioned in question (kotlin version, however same can be done in java)

```
import java.io.File
class RemoveFileContent {
    fun deleteContentAtIndex(filePath: String, indexPos: Int) {
        val bufferedWriter = File("/SampleOutputFile.txt").bufferedWriter()
        File(filePath).readLines().filterIndexed { i, _ -> i != indexPos }.forEach {
            bufferedWriter.appendLine(it)
        }
        bufferedWriter.flush()
    }
}
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    RemoveFileContent().deleteContentAtIndex("/SampleFile.txt",2)
}

Input :             Output:
    hi                  hi
    hello               hello
    hii                 helloo
    helloo
```

**Disclaimer** : Note that if your file content are huge, this can lead to high memory consumption, as stated here - [How to remove first line of a text file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178397/how-to-remove-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-java)